Fridgidaire fridge making rattling noise
Frigidaire fridge rattling a lot
Hi folks,
Moved into a new place and my fridge is rattling quite a bit. It's distracting and hard to work, my landlord said it's totally normal (of course).
Can someone please help?
Here's a link to the video of the rattling  https://youtube.com/shorts/LFMSzhv1B3Y?si=yiqP-dyQj3tamGUQ

Maybe its just vibrating.  Does it rock if you shake it by hand ?

How old is the fridge? Motor mounts can wear out over time.

The TV in the background is louder and more annoying than the fridge.

Are you sure it's not just simply something inside or outside rattling against the vibrations caused by the compressor?

You are right to be concerned (and imho, annoyed).  Steps I would try, Easiest first:

Shift the fridge a bit (body English). Whatever is causing it may be trivial and go away.
It sounds like fan blades may be hitting something.  Fan is usually found underneath the door toward the back.  Shut Power off to explore.  Flashlight and probably brush/vac to get dust out.  May be a cat toy got into fan.  Bigger danger here is obstruction stops fan and it overheats, then compressor runs hard, hot, and continuously.  Bad for it, your food and electric bill, and landlord’s pocketbook.  Tell them.  (BTW, the cleaning has likely never been done, so this step alone may reduce your bill.)
Pin down source location with rubber tubing/hose to ear (stethoscope) while fridge is running.  If it’s coming from the compressor, that’s major.

A responsible landlord would do these things and say thanks for letting me know.
